# how to make alertActions not to be enabled when a button is executed in real time

Tags: swift, xcode

for example,

When I execute the button, I'd like alertActions not to be enabled(the alertActions are on the UIAlertController, and I execute the button again, I'd like the alertActions to be enabled. I tried the code below, but it seems like they don't change in real time, whenever I execute the button.

```
var testButtonForClick: UIButton!   
var flagForClickChecking:Bool = false

func button(){
       testButtonForClick = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 190, width: 70, height: 70))
       testButtonForClick.setTitle("Tap here", for: .normal)
       testButtonForClick.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
    testButtonForClick.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
       testButtonForClick.addTarget(self, action: #selector(itsIng), for: .touchUpInside)
    ThisCustomView.addSubview(testButtonForClick)
   }


@objc func itsIng() {
    flagForClickChecking = true
}

if self.check == true {
  let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("cancel")})
            alertControllers.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertControllers.addAction(add)

if flagForClickChecking == true {
            add.isEnabled = false
            cancelAction.isEnabled = false
            }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. You have an UIButton on your view and whenever you press it you want your UIAlertController not to have the same actions, correct ? But then, when are you displaying your UIAlertController ?

Comment: @Titouan thank you for your comment. I have an alertviewcontroller and the alertviewcontroller has a view and the view has the button on it and I'd like to make the alert actions on the alertviewcontroller not to be enabled when I click the button (which is on the viewcontroller) and when I press it again, I'd like to make the alert actions to be enabled.

Comment: Have you tried dismissing and then presenting again the UIAlertViewController with updated options ? Seem to be the only way to make it work

Comment: @Titouan ah, I see. you mean, dismissing the alertViewController and then present it again? I'd like to it to change in real time when I press the button.

Comment: @Titouan but thank you very much. I'll try with the idea in another way.

Comment: I may have another idea, i need to test, can you send a picture of what it would be like with the alert action displayed please